# How do I create Visual Studio tasks with Resharper?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper

I'm trying to follow [this guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks) to create tasks in Visual Studio Community 2015 and Resharper is installed. I cannot open the command palette with Resharper and there suggestion of Ctrl+Shift+A to search for actions won't find any task related actions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That guide is for Visual Studio Code, which is entirely different from VS 2015. There is no command palette in VS 2015.

Comment: Thanks! Once ten minutes passes I'll accept your answer.